# Why I am getting different number of train size in KFold

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the `Boston` dataset from Sklearn. I am using `kFold`. The value of the `k` is 5. The code is given below

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=k, shuffle=True)
for train_index, _ in kf.split(X_train):
    fitted_model = model.fit(X_train[train_index], y_train[train_index])
    train_preds = fitted_model.predict(X_train[train_index])
    test_preds = fitted_model.predict(X_test)
    print("Train", train_preds.shape)
    print("Test", test_preds.shape)
```

Here, I am getting a different number of train sizes. I am getting 323 for 1-4 folds and 324 for the 5th fold.

```
Train (323,)
Test (102,)
Train (323,)
Test (102,)
Train (323,)
Test (102,)
Train (323,)
Test (102,)
Train (324,)
Test (102,)
```

However, I need the same number of train sizes. Could you tell me why I am getting the different numbers of train sizes or how can I get the same number of train size in every fold?

Comment: I do not think you use KFold correctly. It takes the full dataset and splits it into k-1 training sets and 1 testing set. You seem to have split the data into two sets yourself.

Comment: @DYZ You can use that way to make a KFold dataset and it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your number of sample don't leave remainder zero when divided the number of splits.

The below is the complete trace of the issue.

1. First at the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed5584/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L357) of `KFold` class in `sklearn` you will see that it inherits the [_BaseKFold](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed55847ee70d363bdbfe14ee4401438fba057/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L267) which then inherits the [BaseCrossValidator](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed55847ee70d363bdbfe14ee4401438fba057/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L49).
2. In the `BaseCrossValidator` class you will see that the split function has a `non-implemented` function `_iter_test_indices` responsible for generating the `test_splits`. This functions is designed to be implemented by the inheriting class which in case comes out to be the `KFold` class.
3. Now we see the implementation of this function in this class which is as below.

```
def _iter_test_indices(self, X, y=None, groups=None):
        n_samples = _num_samples(X)
        indices = np.arange(n_samples)
        if self.shuffle:
            check_random_state(self.random_state).shuffle(indices)

        n_splits = self.n_splits
        #==================================================================
        fold_sizes = np.full(n_splits, n_samples // n_splits, dtype=int)
        fold_sizes[:n_samples % n_splits] += 1
        #==================================================================
        current = 0
        for fold_size in fold_sizes:
            start, stop = current, current + fold_size
            yield indices[start:stop]
            current = stop
```

The thing to note is between the comments. As in your case the dataset if not perfectly divisible the term `n_samples % n_splits` will have a value greater than 0 and hence that would increase the size of the test split which in turn decreases the size of the train split.

The solution -> Resample your X_train to have n_samples perfectly divisible by n_splits. like below:

```
# Consider the below array as your dataset
a = np.random.rand(103,20)
# get the remainder
b = a.shape[0] % n_splits
# drop the remainder samples
a = a[:-1*b]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I do resample X_train perfectly divisible by n_split? Any pseudocode? My current code structure is, 1st: I split the train and test `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)` and then I applied the Kfold, and code is given in the post. As the number of K and the total number of the datasets can varying. I understand the problem you described but not getting any idea about the solution.

Comment: I tried the above solution. But was getting the same problem. I think the problem started with `KFold`. Because, before applying your method the shape of the `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test` is the `(404, 13) (102, 13) (404,) (102,)` and after is the `(404, 13) (101, 13) (404,) (101,)`. You can see the shape of the `X_train` and `y_train` remains the same and creating the problem

Comment: Just make it so that the shape of `X_train` and the `y_train` has it's first dimension completely divisible by `n_splits`.